# Backgroung-image as a prop in a styled component - Typescript and Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

How to use `backgroung-image`, passed as a `prop` in a styled component on a Typescript/Next.js project?

I tried in **styled.ts**

```js
type Props = {
  img?: string
}

export const Wrapper = styled.div<Props>`
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url(${ props => props.img });
  background-size: cover;
`
```

My component is **HomeCard.tsx:**

```js
// ...
type Props = {
  children?: ReactNode
  title: string
  img: string
}

const HomeCard = ({children, title, img}: Props) => {
  return(
    <Wrapper img={img}>         
        {children}
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

The image source is called on **index.js**:

```js
import img1 from '../../public/test.jpg'
// ...
<HomeCard img={img1}>
```

But the output on browser is:

> background-image: url(**src:**/_next/static/media/test.5f344d84.jpg;height:2667px;width:4000px;blur-data-u-r-l:/_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Ftest.5f344d84.jpg&w=8&q=70;);

I tried to remove this with `props.img.replace('src:','')`, does't work.

I guess my error is in typing things.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6z2u.png)

Comment: Try passing the image path in the image source instead, i.e. `<HomeCard img="/test.jpg">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
export const Wrapper = styled.div<Props>`
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("/test.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
`
```

image file need to be in public folder

Answer (score 0):

```
type Props = {
  children?: ReactNode
  title: string
  img: any
}

const HomeCard:NextPage<Props> = ({children, title, img}) => {
  return(
    <Wrapper img={img.src}>         
        {children}
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

> //you must make sure you pass .src at the end of the route